# How to use mod_rewrite to remove a query string withing a CMS

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using a CMS that sends all requests to an index.php file using the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

However in the news section of the site the CMS is generating news links like this: `/news?month=201106`

I want my news links like this: `/news/month/201106` and I will achieve this with PHP code.

I know pretty much how to achieve the rewrite with Apache if it weren't for that catchall I would use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^news/month/(.+)$ news?month=$1
```

However my problem is that the CMS is catching the calls and trying to find /news/month/201106 which it cannot and throws an CMS level 404

I've read up about making exceptions but I can't work out how to get:

1. Apache to catch the rewrite before it gets sent to the catch all
2. The CMS to then process the rewritten URL as normal (ie: receive news?month=201106 and process that as normal)

I'm sure this is probably down to the Rewrite flag and the order in which these directives are written but I just cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Apache to catch the rewrite before it gets sent to the catch all

You can do this by adding a RewriteCond before your `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`, so that it looks something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

> 2) The CMS to then process the rewritten URL as normal (ie: receive news?month=201106 and process that as normal)

The 2nd rule that you had, `RewriteRule ^news/month/(.+)$ news?month=$1` should take care of that.

Comment: Thanks - the principle of this is correct and almost solves my issue - I need the condition to also ignore urls below news as these are getting directed to the CMS eg: /news/month/20101010  I expect I will solve this with a wildcard and will post the solution here once I've done that

Comment: The cond only matches when something *doesn't* start with `/news`, so something like `/news/month/20101010` starts with "/news" and thus won't get rewritten to index.php.

Comment: You are correct and indeed your solution works perfectly.  I think my problem is that my second RewriteRule is wrong - it needs to send to index.php still but with some query string parameters - I need to read up on this particular CMS.  Thanks again